# Происходит ли в данном примере преобразование типа Room во float?

Tags: c++, структуры, struct

В книге Роберт Лафоре пишет:

> Обратите внимание на то, что программа преобразовывает две величины типа Distance к величинам float. Кроме того, при вычислении площади комнаты на самом деле осуществляется преобразование переменной типа Room, хранящей два значения типа Distance, к одному вещественному значению.

Но насколько я понимаю cafeteria.length.feet, cafeteria.length.inches, cafeteria.width.feet, cafeteria.width.inches имеют тип float. Даже если применить typeid().name() можно увидеть, что они типа float. Так почему автор пишет, что типы преобразовываются? Или я что-то не понял?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
struct Distance {
    int feet;
    float inches;
};

struct Room {

    Distance length;
    Distance width;
};

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    Room cafeteria{ {13, 5}, {10, 0} };
    float l, w;
    cout << "Введите длину столовой:\n";
    cout << "Футы: ";
    cin >> cafeteria.length.feet;
    cout << "Дюймы: ";
    cin >> cafeteria.length.inches;
    cout << "Введите ширину столовой:\n";
    cout << "Футы: ";
    cin >> cafeteria.width.feet;
    cout << "Дюймы: ";
    cin >> cafeteria.width.inches;
    l = cafeteria.length.feet + cafeteria.length.inches / 12;
    w = cafeteria.width.feet + cafeteria.width.inches / 12;
    cout << "Площадь столовой равна: " << l*w;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваше утверждение верно. На что хотел обратить внимание автор не понятно, но там действительно нет никакого преобразование велечин.

Comment: @ffk ясно, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Тут действительно происходят преобразования:

```
// 5 и 0 преобразуются из int во float
Room cafeteria{ {13, 5}, {10, 0} };

// feet и 12 преобразуется из int во float,
// причем feet потенциально преобразуется с потерей точности
cafeteria.length.feet + cafeteria.length.inches / 12;
```

Comment: Не, я понимаю, что тип int преобразуется во float. Я не понимаю того, о чем говорит автор.

Answer (score 2):

Целое `feet` и литерал `12` неявно преобразуются во `float`.

UPD: Удалил ошибочное замечание.

Comment: В одном футе 12 дюймов, соответственно для получения футов из дюймов надо разделить на 12.

Comment: @VTT, верно, что-то на меня какое-то затмение нашло.